# Is a single md5 hash a good way to generate an AES key?

Tags: brute-force-attack, aes-gcm

[This site](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/02/encrypt-decrypt-data-golang-application-crypto-packages/) says how to encrypt data using a password in go using AES-GCM.

It says the following:

> When encrypting and decrypting data, it is important that you are using a 32 character, or 32 byte key. Being realistic, you’re probably going to want to use a passphrase and that passphrase will never be 32 characters in length.
>
> To get around this, you can actually hash your passphrase using a hashing algorithm that produces 32 byte hashes. I found a list of hashing algorithms on Wikipedia that provide output lengths. **We’re going to be using a simple MD5 hash. It is insecure, but it doesn’t really matter since we won’t be storing the output.**

Is this true?

So fine, I don't mind using something a bit more secure than MD5, it's easy to replace MD5 with SHA-2.

But another thing hit me:

- Why is something like bcypt/scrypt not required?
- Is AES slow enough to prevent a brute-force attack?

Comment: Characters and bytes are not the same thing since the disco era, and MD5 output is 128 _bits_ which is 16 bytes assuming common (but not universal)  8-bit bytes; it is sometimes _represented_ in hex as 32 characters but that is not the same thing, and misunderstanding that suggests low competence. Although a _good_ PBKDF (not a simple hash, see answers) of 128 bits would be fine, barring _maybe_ quantum.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the password/phrase is in fact a password/phrase, and does not already contain sufficient complexity to prevent guessing (e.g. is not a cryptographically strong random string)...

> Is this true?

No. An attacker will simply guess at the password, and a fast hash function will help them to guess faster. An attacker can try a truly ridiculous number of md5 hashes per second, and will certainly break any password/passphrase that was not generated to be cryptographically strong.

> Why is something like bcypt/scrypt not required?

Slow hashing *is* required, and the information in the article is not good advice. Choosing MD5 because it offers the right digest size out of the box is not justifiable: Stronger 256-bit hash functions exist (e.g. SHA256), and a larger hash digest could easily be truncated down to 256 bits

A cryptographic hash function is not appropriate for use on passwords/passphrases.

> Is AES slow enough to prevent a brute-force attack?

No, and it is not the ciphers responsibility to be slow to prevent brute-force attacks on the key. Assuming that they key is strong enough to be called a key (e.g. a uniformly random bit string), then having a slow cipher is completely non-productive.

So the responsibility for being slow to prevent guessing attacks falls to a step before encryption takes place, namely, the key derivation step. Functions such as Bcrypt/Scrypt/Argon2 are explicitly designed for the purpose.

### Alternatively

If the passphrase was generated randomly and designed to possess sufficient entropy, then using a slow key derivation process is not really necessary or beneficial. In such a case, using [something like HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) would probably be the most appropriate.

### In any case

Selecting MD5 from a list because it seems fine is not a good sign...

Comment: I believe you've missed a point.. It's not MD5 for a password, it's using an MD5 hash as a _key_ to AES. You can brute force raw bytes faster than you can brute force _any_ hash, and since the guarantee is coming from AES, not MD5, I don't think MD5's speed is a limitation. [Whether AES is appropriate you've covered] More significant IMO (and why I was googling this question) is whether or not MD5's weakness WRT collisions would mean more valid keys. My use-case is wanting to hash a file contents to use as a key and I'd prefer not to waste cycles on something cryptographic if not advantageous.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this true?

Although as the author says that the hash is not stored and there is no preimage attack on MD5, the problem with MD5 is; it is very fast, that is a brute force on the passwords can be executed 4 times [faster](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40) than SHA-1 and 30-times from SHA-3. If we assume that we have a plaintext-ciphertext pair we can search the passwords very fastly.

> Why is something like bcypt/scrypt not required?

Required because; Bcrypt uses a configurable iteration count so that you can reduce the speed of passwords search. 10 iteration, 10 times slower, 100 iteration 100 times slower, etc.

> Is AES slow enough to prevent a brute-force attack?

Interestingly, we actually require fast and secure block ciphers. AES is not slow, the problem is the key size and even the minimum $2^{128}$ is infeasible for a brute-force attack.